# Limitations of JavaScript's Function constructor

Tags: javascript

Here is something weird, and I don't know how to overcome it.

Basically, I have this string here:

```
var s = 'var Bla = {variable: true, get: function() { return this.variable;}}; return Bla;'
```

and using the Function constructor to parse this construct.

```
var fn = new Function(s);
```

It works great, except that the inside function 'get' is no longer there .. like it didn't got parsed?!

```
fn().variable  -> is there and returns "true".
fn().get  -> is undefined, not existing.
```

Any ideas?

PS: I edited my original question to indicate what's really missing.

Comment: Because you aren't passing a function to the function constructor.

Comment: I wonder if you are running into the [getter syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/get).  You could try changing the name of that property.

Comment: @Brennan - they're passing a function body to the constructor which is allowed.

Comment: Ah, thanks, was not aware of that

Comment: Btw - eval the same issue. @Brennan: new Function is the function constructor. Check https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function

Comment: can you explain `inside function 'get' is no longer there`? i try it in chrome and all works as expected

Comment: just try `eval` instead `new Function`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you've posted is the equivalent of this:

```
var fn = function() {
    var Bla = {
        variable: true, 
        get: function() { 
            return this.variable;
        }
    };
    return Bla;
}
```

So you can't directly use `fn.variable` or `fn.get` - instead you need to call that function:

```
var x = fn();
alert(x.get()); //alerts true
x.variable = 1;
alert(x.get()); //alerts 1
```

`Bla` is just a local variable within the function, and doesn't get returned from it.  The code could easily just have been:

```
var fn = function() {
    return {
        variable: true, 
        get: function() { 
            return this.variable;
        }
    };
}
```

And you'd get the same effect.  After calling the function, the object returned from it is what contains `variable` and `get`:

[image: example object]

Comment: Sorry I should have been more explicit. This works, however the .get is not part of the return object of Bla .. it's just not there.

Comment: @flyandi Can you explain more?  `Bla` is just a local variable within the function and effectively ceases to exist as soon as the function returns.  The object returned from the function certainly does contain both `variable` and `get`: http://imgur.com/VLm4b7y

Comment: I feel stupid right now .. I literally forgot the () on one of the callers of this routine within my library.. but it was the missing () that caused the issue :-) - Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Your example works fine.

I tried it and issuing:

```
fn().get()
```

returns true as you'd expect.

Comment: @flyandi—any browser that supports ES5 (such as Chrome).

Comment: I did it in chrome.  I opened the debugger and copy and pasted the 2 lines you have into the console.  Then I issued: fn().get();

Comment: also fn().bla returns undefined as i'd expect.  Your first post (edited I see) says you got something different? That doesn't make any sense.  fn() will return the Bla object.  That object has no property "bla".

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, I was missing the () from one of the sub modules which is using the raw constructor :-) .. I modified my post to reflect the correct property ("variable").